# How do I change the value of a constant in all components from one component (REACT NATIVE)

Tags: react-native, redux, components

In my Diseases.jsx,
`const selectedDiseases = diseases.filter((disease) => disease.selected);`

If I pick Diabetes in that screen, `selectedDiseases` is console.logged as
 `[{"id": "Diabetes", "name": "Diabetes", "selected": true}]`

This `selectedDiseases` is being used in many components, but I want to be able to change it in my Profile.jsx sccreen. That means that it should update in all other screens as well. How do I do this?

I tried using `react-redux` but was to no avail. Maybe I was just using it wrongly?

Comment: React Native state management is a big topic, but yes, Redux is a valid option, Context would work too. If you want help with your Redux implementation you would need to post some code.